# Чем является имя свойства объекта?

Tags: javascript

Когда создается объект через литерал, вот так

```
var obj = { property: 1, 123: 'tratata'}
```

или

```
obj.property = 'value'
```

то какими типами являются эти имена свойств в итоге?

Слышал, что именем свойства может быть только строка, но тут не понятно.

Преобразуются ли такие имена в строки ( "property", "123" )?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, [ключом может быть только строка, либо symbol](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-ispropertykey).

И обе приведенные записи эквивалентны следующим:

```
var obj = { 'property': 1, '123': 'tratata'};
obj['property'] = 'value';
```

Comment: symbol это что?

Comment: @Topik, [Symbol](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-symbol-type) - это один из типов в js, наряду со строками, числами и т.д.